# Problemas al sumar un numero con otro en varias matrices

Tags: php

El problema es que me suma las posiciones de las matrices en vez del valor

```
$totalVotos = Array
(



 [0] => Array
        (
            [votos] => 8
            [0] => 8
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [votos] => 9
        [0] => 9
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [votos] => 4
        [0] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [votos] => 10
        [0] => 10
    )

)



foreach ($totalVotos as $numeros) {

            $sumar = $numeros['0'];
            $sumar = explode(' ', $sumar);
            print_r(array_sum($sumar));
        }
```

Comment: El arreglo $totalVotos es un resultado de una consulta a DB

Comment: es un array de arrays verdad ?

Comment: No puedes estructurar mejor tu arreglo, creo que lo complicas mucho cuando puedes hacerlo más fácil

Comment: Como asi Victor?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el arreglo $totalVotos es un arreglo que me regresa la consulta a la DB es por eso que se ve asi, yo uso un foreach (tamb use un while) para recorrer el arreglo y simplificarlo, pero el problema es, que array_sum me esta sumando las posiciones de cada valor en vez del valor mismo

Answer (score 0):

intenta con un acomulador asi:

```
<?php
$totalVotos = Array
(
 0 => Array
        (
            'votos' => 8,
            0 => 8
        ),

1 => Array
    (
        'votos' => 9,
        0 => 9
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'votos' => 4,
        0 => 4
    ),

3 => Array
    (
        'votos' => 10,
        0 => 10
    ),

);
$sumar=0;
foreach ($totalVotos as $numeros) {
    $sumar += $numeros['0'];
}
print_r($sumar);
```

pero si yo lo hiciera lo aria algo asi:

```
print_r(array_sum(array_column($totalVotos, 'votos')));
```

Comment: gracias si me sirvio

Comment: entonces marca como resuelto por favor

Comment: y si el segundo array tiene mas de un elemento? tambien los sumaria ?

Comment: siempre y cuando la posicion `$totalVotos[num][0]` siempre exista y no cambie de dimension

Comment: @junior por eso, si en uno de esos arrayas internos llega haber uno con mas de una posicion solo tomaria la primera posicion

Comment: tomaria la posicion que se aclaro aqui `$sumar += $numeros['0'];` en este caso '0' si nesesitas que tome todas las posiciones de la segunda dimencion del array tendrias que hacer esto `$sumar += array_sum($numeros);`

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo algo de codigo para que veas como se recorren lod arrays anidados con `foreach`, seria algo asi:

```
foreach ($totalVotos as $segundoArray) {
    //declaras una variable que almacenara la sumatoria del cada bucle interno
    $sumar=0;
    foreach ($segundoArray as $valorVoto) {
    //sumas los valores en cada vuelta
        $sumar = $sumar + $valorVoto;
    }

    //imprimes los valores de cada ciclo interno
    print_r(array_sum($sumar));
}
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas como te fue